# How Razor knows when to render page in error state?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

As stated in the title: how does razor know when the page should be rendered in error or normal state?

I need to know this information so I can display a page in error mode with validation messages displayed etc. Unfortunately I cannot simply do `View()` because the code which finds the model in invalid state is in subview.

**EDIT**
I'm trying to do something like this to force razor to render a view in error mode:

```
// just for tests....
// model: a model which was marked as invalid in different controller
// state: state of the model from that controller
public ActionResult asdf(TModel model, ModelStateDictionary state) {
    var result = View(this.Partial, model);
    result.ViewData.ModelState.Clear();
    foreach (var x in state) {
        result.ViewData.ModelState.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT2**
Final solution. In the previous attempt auto-deserialization from Json to c# types didn't work (sic!) so I've decided to receive a plain json string and deserialize it with another library like so:

```
public ActionResult ErrorIndex(string jsonParamsString) {
    var param = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ForceInvalidStateRequestArg<TModel>>(jsonParamsString);

    if (param != null && param.Errors != null) {
        this.ModelState.Clear();
        foreach (var s in param.Errors) {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError(s.PropertyName, s.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    var result = View(this.PartialName, param == null ? this.NewModel : param.Model);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about model validity is stored in `ModelState` object.

Which is accessible in controller like:

```
this.ModelState.IsValid
```

In view:

```
this.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState
```

**To your EDIT:**

You can add model validation errors like this:

```
this.ModelState.AddModelError("key", "an error message");
```

So if you want to force @razor to render validation error messages. It could look like:

```
public ActionResult asdf(TModel model, ModelStateDictionary state) 
{
    var result = View(this.Partial, model);
    result.ViewData.ModelState.Clear();
    foreach (var pair in state.Where(m=> m.Value != null && m.Value.Errors.Any()))
    {
        result.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(pair.Key, string.Join(",",pair.Value.Errors.Select(e=>e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()));
    }  
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. I added a code snippet with this what am I trying to do. Could you have a look again?

Comment: Your edit didn't help. Does it make any difference if I load the subpage (this 'asdf') dynamically with ajax?

Comment: I think not. You should use `AddModelError` as in my updated.

Comment: Ok, both worked. I simply had problems with deserialization of the incoming to the asdf function modelstate. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Ah, now I see it, the validation errors are included with `ModelState` objects from `ModelStateDictionary state`. So your approach was absolutely correct.

Comment: Yeap, exactly. What wasn't working was auto-deserilization of received JSON-ed object and passing it to 'asdf' function. It's done by ASP, so I've change the function's declaration to accept a string and deserialize the object by myself. I used it many times and it always work, so I had no idea why it didn't work now. Anyway - problem solved :) Finally the solution is as in Edit2